# How can I pass a C++ variable to a Processing script?

Tags: java, c++, opencv, image-processing, processing

I have written an application in C++ using openCV libraries to track objects based on their HSV values. The application gets and sets the X and Y co-ordinates for the object being tracked, these are available in the parameters xPos and yPos. I have now got to write a program in Processing v3 and wish to pass the C++ parameters into Processing to be able to pass them to an ardunio and use them to actuate servos etc using the Firmata libraries.

Any help at all would be amazing. Even if it is simply, "you can't do this".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to Kevin's answer you can establish a socket connection between your opencv c++ application and Processing. This can could be TCP or UDP.

There is a nice protocol built on top of UDP called [OSC](http://opensoundcontrol.org/introduction-osc) which you might want to use and send a message with the xPos,yPos arguments.

If you simply use Processing just to send some Arduino messages, consider using [OpenFrameworks](http://openframeworks.cc). It's inspired by Processing, so there are a lot similarities (setup()/draw() loops, etc.) and you can use [ofxCv](https://github.com/kylemcdonald/ofxCv) for your OpenCV needs in c++.
OpenFrameworks ships with a serial library, but also has a Firmata based setup too. See [ofArduino](http://openframeworks.cc/documentation/communication/ofArduino/) for more details.

If you simple want to track coloured objects and pass their coordinates to an Arduino, you might like the [Pixy cam project](http://www.cmucam.org/projects/cmucam5):

[image: pixy cam image 1]

[image: pixy cam image 2]

Comment: Thanks for your help, the Pixycam is very interesting, but as this is one element of my undergrad project, the idea of the project is to achieve this as cheaply as possible. It is added to the books for future reference though! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to use [JNA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Access) or [JNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface) in your Processing sketch. This would allow you to call your C++ application from your Processing code.

Think about it this way: instead of your C++ application calling your Processing sketch, your Processing sketch would call your C++ application. Then you would just have to provide functions in your C++ application that return the values you need to use in your Processing sketch.

Another option would be to simply rewrite your C++ application in Java, using one of the Java OpenCV libraries that already work with Processing. That's probably what I would recommend.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way would to be open a socket in your C++ application and pump data directly to your java application/script on your local loopback. There are a plethora of tutorials on sockets/TCP/UDP programming out there, so I won't get too specific here. Despite being a little more complicated to setup initially, I would suggest using TCP over using UDP.

If you're using Linux, ROS is great at connecting different modular applications (despite being geared towards robotics) and takes care of all the difficult work for you. It also has a lot of OpenCV modules.

Shared memory spaces would ultimately be much more difficult to achieve.